# figuring out why push notification is not working

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, ionic3, loopback

Ok guys so basically I have to fix this but I'm not very sure how to since the code it is not mine and it is not commented at all, this app runs 3 folders: app (frontend), backoffice (backend) and api (apirest). Using ionic for the frontend, gulp and triangular for the backend and loopback for the api and mongodb for the database.

this app used to count with notifications but sundenly stop working, and here is where the problem comes.

I have an admin panel where notifications can be send by clicking a button, once this is donde, this code runs

```
.controller('NoticiasController', function ($scope, $rootScope, $state, $timeout, $q, $mdDialog, $mdToast, News, Notification) {


    $scope.notifyAsk = function(news){
        var confirm = $mdDialog.confirm()
            .title('¿Are you sure to notify?')
            .ok('acept')
            .cancel('cancel');

        $mdDialog.show(confirm).then(function () {
            $mdToast.show({
                template: '<md-toast><span flex>Notification sent</span></md-toast>',
                position: 'top right',
                hideDelay: 3000
            });
            $scope.notify(news.category, news.title, news.desc, news.id);
        });
    };

    $scope.notify = function(tag, title, description, idnew){

        Notification.notify({
            tag: tag,
            title: 'News',
            message: title,
            description: description,
            type: 'warning',
            id: idnew
        });
    };
  };
```

but what I'm not sure is this -> Notification.notify  <- comming from, the code is not commented and I'm a beginner using these tecnologies, it is a kind of conection with database or something... how is this supose to send the message, I don't see any action as a result of this function call

could you have any idea?

Comment: Notification might be some 3rd party library that is being used. Did you console before it in the $scope.notify function?

Comment: so this is what returns when I do console.log(Notification) ƒ Resource(value) {
          shallowClearAndCopy(value || {}, this);
        }